# How to Select from into outfile csv with column names

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I have looked at many SO questions, all of them provide a way for this by hardcoding the column names in the select call. But I need something for all column names.

> SELECT * from deviceDetails, connectionDetails where deviceDetails.rowStatus='0' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/devices.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

I need all the column names. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind tab-separated values, you can try this:

From the linux prompt,

```
mysql yourdb -B -e "
SELECT * from deviceDetails, connectionDetails where deviceDetails.rowStatus='0';
" > /path/to/file.tsv
```

The options mean:
-B (batch)
-e (execute)